# Why current directory doesn't change in makefile?

Tags: make, cd-command

I'm trying to run a simple script- clone a git repository into a certain directory, then `cd` to this directory in order to execute an installation script.

This script is in a Makefile.

But the `cd` seems not to be working. It doesn't find my installation script.

I added a pwd after the `cd` in the script, and it shows me the directory from where I'm executing the script, not the directory where I `cd` into.

What's the problem?

```
git clone http://somerepo ~/some_dir
cd ~/some_dir/
pwd
python myscript.py install
```

=>

`pwd`: `/hereIsPathToDirectoryFromWhichIRunTheScript`

> python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

It also doesn't work with `./setup.py`.

If I enter the absolute path `~/some_dir/setup.py` the script fails later because it's trying to access resources in the same folder.

Comment: Can you try something like:
"alias mycd='cd some_dir';mycd"

Comment: That doesn't work: `/bin/sh: mycd: command not found`

Comment: I found the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789594/how-to-write-cd-command-in-makefile had to add a ; after the cd and then execute the script in the same line.

Answer (score 58):

You're using a makefile. Makefiles aren't scripts, each line is executed in a new shell. Meaning when you change the environment in line (such as `cd`), that change is not propagated to the next line.

The solution is that when you want to preserve the environment between commands, you run all the commands in the same line. All the commands will then be executed in the same shell, and the environment is preserved.

For example:

```
target:
    git clone http://somerepo ~/some_dir
    cd ~/some_dir/ && python myscript.py install
```

Comment: Also see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30590240/9334962) for an updated answer.

Comment: Updated answer on this very same page, see below.

Answer (score 5):

since GNU  `make` version 3.82  you can add `.ONESHELL:` on the top of your Makefile and then `cd folder` will do the trick as you expect.
[Read the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html)

Answer (score 1):

A script is run in a [**subshell**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell), which means it has its own `$PWD`. Once it exits you get the "old" `$PWD`. If you want to keep the `$PWD` you need to `source` (aka. `.`) the script instead of running it. This won't work in a Makefile, however, because each *command* is run in a separate subshell:

```
$ pwd
/home/user
$ cat test.sh
cd /
$ cat Makefile
test:
    . ./test.sh && pwd
    pwd
$ make test
. ./test.sh && pwd
/
pwd
/home/user
```

Comment: I found the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789594/how-to-write-cd-command-in-makefile had to add a ; after the cd and then execute the script in the same line.