# Using mktemp in makefile

Tags: io-redirection, make, mktemp

I want to create a temporary file and pipe some text into it using a makefile.

In bash, I can create a temp file and pipe text into it like so:

```
temp_file=$(mktemp)
echo "text goes into file" > ${temp_file}
cat ${temp_file}
rm ${temp_file}
```

Output when running it (as expected):

```
    text goes into file
```

When using the same code in a makefile, I get the following output:

makefile:

```
test:
    temp_file=$(mktemp)
    echo "text goes into file" > ${temp_file}
    cat ${temp_file}
    rm ${temp_file}
```

`$make test`

```
    echo "text goes into file" >  /bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near
    unexpected token `newline' /bin/sh: -c: line 1: `echo "text goes into
    file" > ' make: *** [makefile:18: test] Error 2
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here or if I'm missing any special makefile syntax rules?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why current directory doesn't change in makefile?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150786/why-current-directory-doesnt-change-in-makefile) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789594/how-do-i-write-the-cd-command-in-a-makefile/30590240#30590240

Comment: To elaborate on the suggested previous answers: Each line of your makefile is executed in a separate shell, so the assignment from one line doesn't make it into the next one. You need to write either super long lines that do all at once or use .ONESHELL.

Comment: @Wieland: Yes, this worked for me. I managed to concatenate the lines with backslashes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that each line in a recipe is run in a separate shell invocation, so shell variables set in one line aren’t visible in subsequent lines (see [Why current directory doesn't change in makefile?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/150786/86440)). On top of that, you need to double the `$` signs so that the shell sees `$`.

However, instead of using shell variables here, you can use Make variables:

```make
TEMP_FILE := $(shell mktemp)
test:
    echo "text goes into file" > $(TEMP_FILE)
    cat $(TEMP_FILE)
    rm $(TEMP_FILE)
```